# Call postgres data source only once when using on multiple charts in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have created a PostgreSQL data source and have multiple charts that show different data using it. The charts are on the same page and are using the same data source. I have around 10 charts with the same source but different filters and metrics.

Now what is happening is that the same query is being run on my DB 10 times. How can I reuse the data source such that the query is run only once and then the charts use its data?